# Adding user inputted numbers within a function

Tags: python

I am new to creating user-defined functions in python and I was wondering what is going wrong here, I am basically trying to get the user to input a number which is the amount of numbers they wish to add together. The program will then ask them to enter a number for the amount of times the previously entered number states. For instance, if the user entered 3, the program would ask them to enter three different numbers. Then program will then utilise the function I created to add those numbers together.

```
def add_multi(x):
    z = 0
    for i in range(y):
        z = z + x   
    return z

y = int(input("Enter amount of numbers you wish to add: "))

for i in range(y):
    x = int(input("Enter number: "))

print(add_multi(x))
```

I go to input 2 for the amount numbers I wish to add together, and I then choose the numbers 2 and 1 to add together. Usually this would output 3 but it somehow outputs the number 2 and I have no idea why.

If anyone can help it would be greatly appreciated as I am completely stuck.

Comment: Ah, that makes a lot more sense thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(1) scrap add_multi, (2) create a list to store multiple numbers, (3) and return a value to print.

```
y = int(input("Enter amount of numbers you wish to add: "))
list_of_inputs = []
for i in range(1, y+1):
    x = int(input("Enter number: "))
    list_of_inputs.append(x)

print(sum(list_of_inputs))
```

Comment: I'm glad you learned from the plethora of answers provided. It's helpful for the asker (you) to mark one answer as correct so others with similar questions can find the best solution.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add *multiple* numbers that a user inputs, you need to store more than one number, so you need a list. Here's how to fix your input:

```
user_input = []  # An empty list.
for i in range(1, y+1):
   x = input("Enter number (%d of %d): " % (i, y))
   user_input.append(int(x))
```

Now your task is to sum all numbers in `user_input`. This can be done in many ways; read the docs on [`for` statement](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#for-statements), for instance.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I knew variables could only store one piece of data, don't know why it didn't occur to me

Comment: A variable named `user_input` stores many pieces of data, being a list :) But `input()` returns one piece of data, and you have to append it to the list every time you receive a new one. "Variables" are just names pointing to objects, and these objects can have an arbitrarily complex structure (consider lists of lists, etc).

Answer (score 1):

The logic is off a bit. you are trying to store two numbers into one variable as numbers. Try storing into an array an using arrays to calc the rest. like this:

```
z=[]
y = int(input("Enter amount of numbers you wish to add: "))

for i in range(y):
    x = int(input("Enter number: "))
    z.append(x)
print(sum(z))
```

Answer (score 0):

The way your code is written currently, it can't accept more than one number as an input to add because of these lines:

```
for i in range(y):
    x = int(input("Enter number: "))
```

When you input 1 after inputting 0, 1 overwrites the previous 'x' value and then 'add_multi' is called with 1 as the input.

This is the reason why you are getting two as an output as well. The issue occurs in the following lines:

```
z = 0
for i in range(y):
    z = z + x
```

Since x = 1 and y = 2, what happens is:

```
// To start off, z = 0
z = 0 + 1 // Now, z = 1 
z = 1 + 1 // Now, z = 2
```

To solve the issues, add the inputs to an array like the other user mentioned above and then change your function to be the following.

```
def add_multi(arr):
    sum = 0
    for num in arr:
    // The 'for' loop goes through each element of the array and lets
    // you use the element as the variable 'num' (the name can be
    // anything you want it to be btw)
         sum += num
    return sum
```

Comment: guess I need to look up about arrays and familiarise myself with them then, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

While the other responses here are much more efficient, I tried to keep things simple for you and also maintain your user defined function.

Initialize your running total `z` at the beginning and for each iteration of `y`, call add_multi to add the input x to the running total `z`.  Then at the end, print the total `z`.

It's very rudimentary and could be optimized once you get a better handle on the language.

```
def add_multi(x,z):
    return z + x   

y = int(input("Enter amount of numbers you wish to add: "))
z = 0

for i in range(y):
    x = int(input("Enter number: "))
    z = add_multi(x,z)

print(z)
```

Comment: thanks for the help, that makes a lot more sense than what I was trying to do earlier